# Javascript Closure not taking inputs consistently

Tags: javascript, syntax, closures

I have two javascript closures and I'm trying to understand why one will accept and input with a particular syntax and the other will reject.

```
function multiply(factor) {

  var ace = (function(number) {
      return number*factor;
  });

  return ace;

} 

var yup = multiply(4);
console.log(yup(5));
```

This outputs 20 to the console as it should.

The second Closure I have is

```
var k = 3;
var add = (function () {
  console.log(k);
  var counter = k;
  return function (j) {counter += 1; return counter*j}
})(k);

add();
console.log(add(5));
```

The output is 20 as it should be.

This issue I'm having that if I try to use the syntax of

```
(function() {

})(number);
```

In the first closure it does not work and outputs "number is not defined"
And if I try to input into the second closure

```
(function (k) {
  var counter = k;
  return function (j) {counter += 1; return counter*j}
});
```

I get out

```
function (j) {counter += 1; return counter*j}
```

to the console.

My question is, what am I not understanding about closers the `()` at the end of them.

Comment: because you are not using k passed in.... you are using the global variable....

Comment: *"what am I not understanding about closers the () at the end of them."* `()` just calls the function. Just like `foo(42)`. If `foo` is `function foo(x) { console.log(x); }` you could inline the function definition and do `(function foo(x) { console.log(x);})(42)`. That's the same as doing `foo(42)`. This has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: You are passing a parameter to the anonymous function, but the function is declared with *no* parameters.

Comment: `(function(){})();` is simply an immediately invoked functional expression (or IIFE) for short.  It works exactly like normal functions, in regards to variable scope

Answer (score 0):

The difference is whether you are creating the closure right away through an IIFE, or a function that makes the closure when called.

Your first snippet written in the second style would be

```
var yup = (function multiply(factor) {
  return function ace(number) {
    return number*factor;
  };
})(4); // the multiply(4) call is inlined into the statement with the definition
console.log(yup(5));
```

Your second snippet written in the first style would be

```
function makeAdd(k) {
  console.log(k);
  var counter = k;
  return function (j) {
    counter += 1;
    return counter*j;
  }
}
var add = makeAdd(3);
add();
console.log(add(5));
```