# Javascript Closure Variables Initialize Only Once?

Tags: javascript

Simple JS logic question here.. In the below code, why does add() only set counter to 0 once? I feel like every time the function is called it should reset it to zero.

```
var add = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter}
})();
add(); // 1
add(); // 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because `var counter = 0;` is run only once. You're assigning and calling the inner function, the outer one is *immediately invoked*. Add some `console.log`s and see the flow of control.

Comment: You're using an IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression, means it self executes immediately and only once, you cannot explicitly call it like you are trying to do.  Like @slebetman has stated in their answer, when you call add (  ) you are not calling the IIFE, instead you are calling the function that was returned when the IIFE first executed, in which you are incrementing the counter. That is the reason your counter's value keeps going up. And yes, closure's variables in case of IIFEs are only initialized once becuase IIFE runs only once.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I had no idea about IIFE's. Knowing they execute only one solves my confusion. Time for to Google more about them

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55230521/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the code. The function `add()` does not contain the code `var counter = 0`.

Here's a rewrite of the exact same code that makes it more clear:

```
var add;

// Note: THIS function is NOT add()
(function () {
  var counter = 0;

  // THIS function is add()
  add = function () {counter += 1; return counter}
})();

add(); // 1
add(); // 2
```

The code above does exactly the same thing as your original code except for how `add` was assigned. In your code it was assigned via a return value but in the above I simply assigned it directly as a global variable to make it more clear which function is `add()`.

Another way to look at it that is more like your original code is to explicitly name the two functions:

```
var function1 = function () {
  var counter = 0;

  // The returned function is what will be assigned to add()
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter}
}; // Do not call it yet since calling it was what was confusing you

var add = function1();

add(); // 1
add(); // 2
```